how to access hierarchical route resolver data in Angular
First and foremost, here's a stackblitz of the issue I'm facing.
Let's say I have a route in my application that looks like /projects/{projectId}/files/{fileId}.
I have a projectResolver defined at the /projects/{projectId} route (and subsequent child routes) that will call the API and load the project data.
I have a second fileResolver defined at the /projects/{projectId}/files/{fileId} to load the specific file from the API.  However, in order to load that file, I need information defined on the project object that's resolved from the projectResolver.
When I try to access the route, I can see the project endpoints being called, and object is resolved.  However, if I try to access that project from the activatedRouteSnapshot.data in the fileResolver, the data is not present.
Is there a way to access data from other resolvers "higher up" in the route chain?
